# Enabling URL Rewriting with ASP.NET using web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, plesk

I am brand new to `ASP.NET`, in fact I know pretty much nothing about it, but do not despair, I am **not** looking for a tutorial... A colleague of mine is wanting to run an `ASP.NET` application on our Webserver. Our Webserver is running Windows 2008 R2, with Plesk 11 and IIS 7.5.

So far I have had all sorts of problems trying to enable `ASP.NET`, but after a lot of fiddling around, I managed to get the application working (to a certain extent).

However, in order to get the application to work, I had to remove the following lines from my `web.config` file:

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
        <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
            <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

This was because I was receiving the error:

> Parser Error Message: Section or group name 'system.webServer' is
>   already defined. Updates to this may only occur at the configuration
>   level where it is defined.

My folder structure is like so:

```
website/
    TestApplication/
        web.config
    index.php
    web.config
```

I have created an Application for the folder 'TestApplication' (not that I really know what this means), but this has not made any difference.

**I was under the impression that if you create an application, the `web.config` inside the directory will *not* inherit any of the parent configurations!** This does not seem to be the case here as I am still receiving the error.

My question is, what am I meant to do with the above situation? How can I either prevent the application from inheriting the parent directories configurations, or alternatively, fix the current `web.config` file to work with `ASP.NET`?

*One thing to note, I have made changes in both IIS Manager, and Plesk as I was unable to find particular things in the Plesk Control Panel, for instance: creating an application for a directory within a website. I don't think this is the cause of the issue here, but nevertheless, worth mentioning.*

### UPDATE

This is my full web.config file (with all bar one of my rules removed as they have no impact on the file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
        <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
            <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Browser Error Rewrite" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^errors/browser$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="_errors/browser.php?error=browser" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors>
            <clear />
            <error statusCode="400" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="502" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=502" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="407" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=407" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="414" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=414" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="415" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=415" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="501" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=501" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=401" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=405" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=412" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/_errors/error.php?id=406" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors>
        <handlers>
            <clear />
            <add name="PageHandlerFactory-Integrated" path="*.aspx" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" preCondition="integratedMode" />
            <add name="php-5.3.10" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\Additional\PleskPHP53\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule,DefaultDocumentModule,DirectoryListingModule" resourceType="Either" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did you try IIS url rewrite module? [URL rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module)

Comment: @RaviSilva That is what created these `configSections` blocks in the first place, but thanks anyway :-). I have now sorted, will post an answer later

Comment: @Ben Carey - how did you solve it?

Comment: IIS URL Rewrite module won't touch your web.config and generate the `configSections`. If it does, that should be considered a bug. You can remove it from your web.config file safely.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have  twice in your web.config (that's what the "Parser Error Message: Section or group name 'system.webServer' is already defined" error implies).

Search for  in your application's web.config and cut the code in it and paste it to another one(make sure that code doesn't repeating) remove that one you have cut the code from

Comment: Yes this is pretty clear from the error message, however, I cannot remove one of them because I need it in order for the URL rewriting to work!

Comment: can u post your web.config code obviously after removing sensitive information?

Comment: Sure thing, give me two mins :-)

Comment: The config file you are referring to is the master config file, not one that should be edited. Not to mention the fact that it will apply that configuration to all of my websites! I have posted my web.config file

Answer (score -1):

If you are using a newer version of IIS or using Windows Azure, you don't need the `<ConfigSection>`. It is built-in in the new IIS. Simply go ahead and use `<rewrite>` tag directly under `<system.webServer>` in your web.config.

Comment: Not true. Only if you use Azure Web Sites, the module is installed by default. Windows Server or desktop not yet ships with IIS URL Rewrite.